# What is minimum distance between $y = (y_1,y_2)$ and the curve $f(x) = 1/x$?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

This question is a follow up on a question ([Show that $\{ x \in \mathbb R^2 : x_1x_2 = 1 \}$ is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2983045/show-that-x-in-mathbb-r2-x-1x-2-1-is-closed?noredirect=1#comment6156511_2983045)) that I asked earlier. The question is given by the following.

> Given a point $\boldsymbol y = (y_1,y_2), y_1,y_2 \geq 0$, what is the minimum distance between this point and the curve $f(x) = 1/x$?

A natural way to model this would be to consider the distance function $f(x) = (x-y_1)^2 $ $+ (1/x - y_2)^2$, which gives the distance between $\boldsymbol y$ and the function $f(x)$ for some $x \in \mathbb R$. But finding an $x$ where the derivative $df(x)/dx$ is zero is equivalent to finding the root of a 4th degree polynomial... Anyone that has a suggestion on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Do you mean $$d=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$$?

Comment: What does $(y_1,y_2)\geqslant0$ mean?

Comment: The title is unclear. I suggest something like "What is the minimum distance between a given point and the curve $f(x) = 1/x$?"

Comment: Ah sorry guys. To be clear, fix $y \in \mathbb R^2$ where $y = (y_1,y_2)$, moreover the $\geq 0$ is componentwise, i.e. we consider only the first quadrant.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner -- Minimizing distance $d$ is the same as minimizing $d^2$.

Comment: Yes this is true.

Comment: @Adriaan -- The title is still confusing; now it has $x$ a single number, but $y$ a pair of numbers.

Comment: @mr_e_man fixed it..., but the fact that $\boldsymbol y$ was a pair followed both from context and notation.

Comment: The context and notation were not in the title. I guess it's okay now.

Comment: @mr_e_man Thanks for your critique though, keeps me sharp :)

Comment: I considered rotating 45 degrees, or re-parametrizing the hyperbola, but I still get a quartic polynomial.

Comment: @mr_e_man Interesting, it sounds like a straighforward problem in optimisation.

Comment: Why oh why $y$?! There are plenty of letters to choose from, so why pick the one that is guaranteed to cause confusion and misunderstanding? This is the $(x,y)$-plane we are working in, after all.

Comment: @TonyK Hah my reasoning was that if I chose say $x_0$, one would have to actively work with 2 indices for most parameters which would be annoying for the derivation possibly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When some algebraic problem reduces to a general quartic equation, there cannot be any shortcut. Otherwise, you would have discovered a new way to a solve a quartic, and we have sufficient evidence that this is not possible.

We can exhibit cases such that four normals to an equilateral hyperbola are coincident, which shows that four extrema of the distance are possible. Hence, the problem is confirmed to be quartic and you can't simplify that.

[image]